# Name conflicts in Vaadin WidgetSet

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, liferay, vaadin

I am working on integrating third party javascript libraries into a Vaadin WidgetSet for a Liferay portal. I am using Vaadin version 6.7.3 and Liferay 6.1.

There are, so far, two independent projects and each generates a differente jar file. The `inherits` element is the same in both the cliend-side module descriptors:

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.portal.gwt.PortalDefaultWidgetSet" />
```

When I use the Vaadin Liferay Control Panel to recompile my WidgetSet, I see that the results of the compilation are dumped into `tomcat-folder/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.portal.gwt.PortalDefaultWidgetSet`, which is expected.

Each Widget defines their own javascript and stylesheets in their client-side module descriptors like so:

#### Widget 1

```
<script src="script_1.js"></script>
<stylesheet src="styles_1.css"></stylesheet>
```

#### Widget 2

```
<script src="script_2.js"></script>
<stylesheet src="styles_2.css"></stylesheet>
```

Since each javascript file and stylesheet is named differently, I see that the folder `tomcat-folder/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.portal.gwt.PortalDefaultWidgetSet` does contain `script_1.js`, `script_2.js`, `styles_1.css` and `styles_2.css`.

The problem is that there are name clashes. Both widgets define styles and functions in their stylesheets/javascript files, but some names are the same, which leads to unexpected behaviour. Using firebug, I have confirmed that both stylesheets and both javascript files are loaded when using either one of the widgets. I have also checked that if I undeploy one of the widgets and recompile the widget set, it works perfectly.

Since those javascripts and stylesheets are actually third party provided and have been obfuscated for my reading pleasure, it would be a bit tedious to go through all names to resolve conflicts.

I have tried to force the gwt compiler to rename the widgetset by passing properties in the client-side module descriptor, like so:

```
<set-property name="widgetset" value="custom.widgetset.FooBarWidgetSet"/>
```

And also like so:

```
<set-configuration-property name="widgetset" value="custom.widgetset.FooBarWidgetSet"/>
```

I was expecting that for each widget, a different folder under `tomcat-folder/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN/widgetsets` for each widget would be created, but it didn't work. To be honest, I am not sure if this is even possible, since the Vaadin Liferay Control Panel has a field stating *Active WidgetSet* (see [this related image](http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/vaadin-6/html/img/portal/liferay-control-panel-1.png))

My question is: how is it possible to resolve name conflicts across different stylesheets/javascript files?